# Add more GET data for Javascript

Tags: javascript, get

I am using the javascript below to send information from one website to another, but I don't know how to add more data. ?url is fine. I'm not sure how to add more data to the javascript. I would like to add an ?img, a ?title ... i tried a few times but no luck. Help please.

#### JavaScript

```
 onclick="window.open('http://mysite.com/submit.?url='+(document.location.href));return false;"
```

#### PHP

```php
$url = $_GET['url'];
```

Comment: Use an ampersand (encoded in this example for the source): `?url=blah&amp;other=stuff`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Separate the parameters with `&`.

```
http://mysite.com/submit?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3
```

You should also encode your values with [`encodeURI()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript/332888#332888).

Comment: The only addition I have is to use an encoded `&amp;` for what will be outputted to the browser.

Comment: @JaredFarrish, this is in JavaScript, not HTML.  Escaping HTML entities is irrelevant here.

Comment: Even though it's in an `onclick` attribute handler? (Which is what I was thinking.)

Comment: @JaredFarrish, Oh, in that case, you are correct.  I missed that part,  I assumed he was going to put this in a script somewhere.

Comment: @Brad `http://mysite.com/submit.?url='+(document.location.href)&title=+(document.title));` so as you probably guessed I suck at Javascript. Can you please give me an example? I've tried to change the code a few times without any luck. What I'm trying to do is grab the url and title of a page and use it in wordpress to create a new post.So a `$title = $_GET['title'];` will also be used. Thank you

Comment: @ciprian, Try this:  `'http://mysite.com/submit?url=' + encodeURIComponent(document.location.href) + '&title=' + encodeURIComponent(document.title)`   The `+` symbol is used for concatenation (sticking two strings together) in JavaScript, so you must put that in between everything you want to concatenate.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't add `?moreParm...etc`, you use an ampersand (`&`) to add additional parameters.

```
var url = `http://mysite.com/submit.?url=' + document.location.href;
url += '&anotherParam=foo`;
// etc.
```

You need to escape all parameter values accordingly.

I'd also recommend moving it into a function so your embedded JS doesn't become impossible to read.